# unset X-Varnish header to the backend server but keep it in the response to client

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl, varnish-4

Currently, I migrate a configuration from Varnish 3 to Varnish 6.

But I have an issue concerning unset a header to a backend but keep it in the resp.

Indeed, I cannot use it in vcl_backend_response because it's unset before (vcl_pass/vcl_backend_fetch)...

In the documentation (https://book.varnish-software.com/4.0/chapters/VCL_Subroutines.html), I can see that "if you do not wish to send the X-Varnish header to the backend server, you can remove it in vcl_miss or vcl_pass. For that case, you can use unset bereq.http.x-varnish;." but I cannot use bereq in vcl_miss/vcl_pass.

Do you have any idea how to keep this header in vcl_backend_response but without send it to backend?

In Varnish 3, I used it in vcl_miss/vcl_pass and the unset bereq was set in vcl_fetch.

Best regards,

```
vcl 4.1;
import std;

backend dev {
  .host = "127.0.0.1";
  .port = "8080";
}

sub vcl_recv {
  set req.http.App="App1";
  set req.backend_hint = dev;
  return (hash);
}

sub vcl_miss {
  unset req.http.App;
}

sub vcl_pass {
  unset req.http.App;
}

sub vcl_backend_fetch {
  unset bereq.http.App;
}

sub vcl_backend_response {
  if (bereq.http.App) {
    set beresp.http.Debug = "test";
    set beresp.ttl = 10s;
    set beresp.grace = 10s;
    return (deliver); // not applied
  }
}

sub vcl_deliver {
  set res.http.App;
}
```

- Currently: App header in unset for backend & client (unable to use it
  in vcl_backend_response)
- Goal: App header can be used for conditions in vcl_backend_response but not sent to the backend

Comment: Please see https://fiddle.fastlydemo.net/fiddle/b7cab501

Comment: It works for me, removing it in `vcl_miss`